# Filter and match multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a list of teams and their corresponding owners in Google Sheets.
(owners own multiple teams)

I have a great formula that will filter the list by owner name:
`=FILTER(A2:A6, MATCH(B2:B6,"RINGO",0))`

I like using filter in case I had stat columns for the team that I wanted to propagate as well.

My problem is that I actually have TWO sets of data, and they are not on the same column.

```
  A         B          C          D
GIANTS    RINGO     ROCKETS     GEORGE
DODGERS   GEORGE    BLUE JAYS   PAUL
PACKERS   PAUL      DUCKS       RINGO
KINGS     PAUL      YANKEES     JOHN
BLAZERS   JOHN      LAKERS      JOHN
OILERS    RINGO     BRUINS      GEORGE
```

I tried using brackets `{_,_}` to expand my ranges:
`=FILTER({A2:A6,C2:C6}, MATCH({B2:B6,D2:D6},"RINGO",0))`
But I get the error "*FILTER range must be a single row or single column.*"

I've been searching for a while now and can't seem to come up with a formula that will give me one list for Ringo: GIANTS OILERS DUCKS

Ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Please do share a link to a sample spreadsheet as well as the desired result. It would be great help to anyone trying to answer your question. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have to "stack" your columns**.

You can do that using the following formula:

```
=FILTER({A4:A10;C4:C10}, MATCH({B4:B10;D4:D10},"RINGO"))
```

**EDIT** *(following your [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133351/filter-and-match-multiple-columns-in-google-sheets/133355?noredirect=1#comment121700_133355))*:

```
=SORT(FILTER({A4:A10;C4:C10}, MATCH({B4:B10;D4:D10},"RINGO")))
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was using , instead of ;

Comment: _"I was using `,` instead of `;`"_. Correct. The way you had your formula you were producing rows.

Comment: One more thing... the formula has to have the sorting feature to get the desired list. `=FILTER({A4:A10;C4:C10}, MATCH({B4:B10;D4:D10},"RINGO",0))`

Comment: Try to use `=SORT()` on your output

Comment: In your question your results were not sorted. In any case try the edited formula.